# jQuery get the value of objects on serializeArray()

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm using jQuery to serialize some responses in a form,

now I need to access the values on the objects, how to do it?

here where I serialize,

```
var dataArray = new Array($('#popup-form').serializeArray());
 
console.log(dataArray);
```

Which gives me:
[image]

So how to acces the values on my object 0... n

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#popup-form').serializeArray()[0];
```

This will do the trick as `.serializeArray()` return you an array already, so you don't need to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var dataArray = $('#popup-form').serializeArray();
console.log(dataArray[0]);
```

Array index starts from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mentioned, you can use:

```
$('#popup-form').serializeArray()[0];
```

To get an array of objects. But if you need only the value, try this:

```
$('#popup-form').serializeArray()[0]['value'];
```

Notice that `[0]` index refers to first object.